# Unclear use of 'wollen'

Tags: translation

I have come across this use of *wollen* in [an article](https://www.spektrum.de/news/warum-schwitzen-wichtig-ist-und-wie-man-zu-viel-schweiss-stoppt/1748490):

> Die verbreitete Annahme, Männer schwitzten stärker als Frauen, **wollen**
> australische Forscher vor drei Jahren in einer Untersuchung mit 60
> Probanden widerlegt haben.

I can guess from the context that the meaning is "The researchers claimed to have proved...". Is this correct?

Comment: Other modal verbs also have less well known uses like this. In grammar literature it is referred to as „subjektiver Gebrauch der Modalverben“, in case you want to read up on this.

Comment: The question was answered but I'd like to add a source which elaborates on this: https://www.deutschplus.net/pages/Subjektive_Bedeutung_der_Modalverben

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your assumption is correct.

See [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/wollen_moechten_wuenschen), meaning 1d).

This usage of *wollen* expresses that the author is skeptical with respect to the researchers' claim.

Comment: that's nonsense. konjunktiv 1 is not sceptical, jts agnostic and the usual mood for reported speech. preterite would mean konjunktiv 2, irrealis, so that's principally not used. those distictions are a minefield however, because there's no strict rule that summaries had to be written in present tense.